# Upgrade to Magento 2.0.1 Using Composer Readiness Check Fails

Tags: magento2, upgrade, patches, composer

I have a brand new install of Magento 2.0.0 with only the sample data installed.  I had the critical update warning to patch to 2.0.1.  Using the Web Setup Wizard in the dashboard, I get as far as selecting the latest version and all components to update,  but when the readiness check takes place it gives me the following error, all other checks are completed fine.

> Check Component Dependency
>
> We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail
>
> For additional assistance, see component dependency help .

I followed the guideline link but it is less than helpful!  Here is the code from my composer.json file that it suggests may be wrong.  I have no idea where I am supposed to go next from here.  Any help or advise would be hugely appreciated.

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.0.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.0",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.0.*",
    "magento/sample-data-media": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.0.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.0.6",
    "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to go with Magento 2.0.2 version. It works perfectly for us with all latest patches.

Answer (score 0):

Today many users has complained about it, and it seems to be M2 bug..

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3065
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3059
.. 3056

I suggest to wait a bit and see what magento developers recommend.. :)